# Finding a single cluster of points with low variance

Tags: algorithm, statistics, cluster-analysis

Given a collection of points in the complex plane, I want to find a "typical value", something like mean or mode. However, I expect that there will be a lot of outliers, and that only a minority of the points will be close to the typical value. Here is the exact measure that I would like to use:

> Find the mean of the largest set of points with variance less than some programmer-defined constant C

The closest thing I have found is the article [Finding k points with minimum diameter and related problems](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/019667749190022Q), which gives an efficient algorithm for finding a set of k points with minimum variance, for some programmer-defined constant k. This is not useful to me because the number of points close to the typical value could vary a lot and there may be other small clusters. However, incorporating the article's result into a binary search algorithm shows that my problem can be solved in polynomial time. I'm asking here in the hope of finding a more efficient solution.

Comment: do you need k points or single point?

Comment: A single point will do fine (once I have a single point, it shouldn't be hard to determine which points are nearby).

Comment: There is a way to remove any precentage of points you want such that the variance is at most (1+epsilon) times the optimal variance (where optimal variance means the minimum variance you can achive by removing this precentage of points) and the time complexity of the algorithm is O(n/sqrt(epsilon)). The algorithm is pretty complicated but if you're still intrested in this problem I can explain it when I'll have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is way to do it (from what i have understood of problem) : -

1. select the point k from dataset and calculate sorted list of points in ascending order of their distance from k in `O(NlogN)`.
2. Keeping k as mean add the points from sorted list into set till variance < C and then stop.
3. Do this for all points
4. Keep track of set which is largest.

Time Complexity:- `O(N^2*logN)` where N is size of dataset

Comment: Thanks so much for answering! I will use your algorithm as a starting point and see if it is fast enough. I may need to switch to some kind of quick-and-dirty almost-linear method that does a pretty good job most of the time.

Comment: @realguy You can make the above algorithm O(N*k + NlogN) using kd-tree where K is size of largest set. Use kdtree to get nearest neighbours in O(logN + k)

Answer (score 0):

Mode-seeking algorithms such as Mean-Shift clustering may still be a good choice.
You could then just keep the mode with the largest set of points that has variance below the threshold `C`.

Another approach would be to run k-means with a fairly large `k`. Then remove all points that contribute too much to variance, decrease `k` and repeat. Even though k-means does not handle noise very well, it can be used (in particular with a large `k`) to identify such objects.

Or you might first run some simple outlier detection methods to remove these outliers, then identify the mode within the reduced set only. A good candidate method is 1NN outlier detection, which should run in `O(n log n)` if you have an R-tree for acceleration.

Comment: Having all these different leads is very helpful. I'll probably try all of these and see what works best.